# Is there any possibility to connect with Raspberry PI 2 through the mobile network

Tags: raspberry-pi2

I am currently working on internet of things technology, in one of my scenarios I want to connect raspberry pi2 through the mobile network.

Please tell me is there any possibility to connect with raspberry pi2 through the mobile network.

Regards,
Pradeep

Comment: I would propose this stackexchange site: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/, and particularly this question: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9802/3g-dongle-setup

Answer (score 0):

You can connect your Pi2 to a mobile network using either a [USB 3G Dongle](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-setup-usb-3g-modem-raspberry-pi-using-usbmodeswitch-and-wvdial) or a [3G Shield](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/3g-gps-shield-arduino-raspberry-pi-tutorial/).

You will have to play around with the setup though to see how it works for you.

If you want to access your Pi2 from elsewhere while connected to a mobile network you will also need to setup [dynamic ip resolution for your Pi](http://blog.mivia.dk/free-dynamic-dns-for-raspberry-pi/) if you do not have a fixed ip assigned by your mobile operator.

If, however you want to connect from a mobile device to your Pi2 which is located on a LAN, you will need to configure port forwarding on your router for the Pi2 to receive communication from the outside world. Once again, if your router does not have a fixed ip supplied by your ISP, you will need to setup a dynamic ip resolution (DDNS).

Hope this helps.